# Methods inside Methods?

Tags: java, methods

I want to have following:

```
Permissions.getPermissions().add("STRING");
```

I would need to have the Class Permissions, The Method getPermissions() and inside that Method another one called add() right? But that is not possible as you can't have a Method inside of an Method :/
Is there any way around this?

Comment: That’s not what it means. It means add is called on whatever is returned by getPermissions (maybe a Set or List).

Answer (score 3):

It is absolutely possible and it is not a method inside a method. What's happening in your example is that your first method is returning an object which has a method of its own. For instance imagine the following: you have a Zoo class. That zoo class has a zookeeper and therefore a method to fetch the zoo keeper. That method will return an instance of the Person class. That class has a method to get the person's name. As a result you could write:

```
zoo.getZookeeper().getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need a method inside another. Your full example would be:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MyClass {
           
       public List<String> permissions;
       
       public List<String> getPermissions(){
           return permissions;
       }
       
       MyClass(){
           permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
       }
   }
```

And then:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.getPermissions().add("STRING");
           
System.out.println(obj.permissions.toString());
```

which will result in:

```
[STRING]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible and it is not called method inside method instead it a reference  and operations are performed on that reference.

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


class Permissions {
    final static private List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();

    public static List<String> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }
}

public class SampleMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Permissions.getPermissions().add("STRING");
        Permissions
                .getPermissions()
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```